# Calculating date for a day of the week

Tags: algorithm, t-sql, datetime, pseudocode

Given a week-day (1-7), how can I calculate what that week-day's last date was?

**Example:** Today is **Wednesday**, 2008/11/12, and I want to know what last **Friday's** date was.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `today` is the current day of the week, then you can use something like:

```
days_since_friday = (((today - 1) + 7) - (6 - 1)) % 7
```

This assumes that Friday is represented by day number 6 of the week (that is, 1 represents Sunday). Then subtract `days_since_friday` from the current date, and you'll get the date of the end of last week.

The above expression is slightly more complicated than it needs to be. If your day-of-week started at 0 for Sunday, it simplifies to:

```
days_since_friday = ((today + 7) - 5) % 7
```

or

```
days_since_friday = (today + 2) % 7
```

Comment: is "today" the day of the week or the day of the month?

Comment: "today" is today's day of the week.

Answer (score 4):

In general?  See [Calendrical Calculations](http://emr.cs.uiuc.edu/home/reingold/calendar-book/index.shtml).

In this narrower case of within the previous week?  Find the difference in days (Friday = 5, Wednesday = 3).  Find differences in weeks (last week = -7 days).  When you've found the offset in days+weeks, apply that offset to the calendar date.